# QueryDSL Window functions

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

How can I write a query using window functions and selecting all fields in QueryDSL?
In the docs there is an example like this:

```
query.from(employee)
.list(SQLExpressions.rowNumber()
    .over()
    .partitionBy(employee.name)
    .orderBy(employee.id));
```

but I need to generate a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT employee.name, employee.id, row_number() 
    over(partition BY employee.name
    ORDER BY employee.id)
  FROM employee) AS sub
WHERE row_number = 1
```

And is it possible to do it with JPAQuery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JPAQuery supports only the expressivity of JPQL, so window functions are not supported, but paging should work using

```
query.from(employee).orderBy(employee.id).limit(1)
```

In case you need to use window functions and you need employee.name and employee.id out this should work

```
NumberExpression<Long> rowNumber = SQLExpressions.rowNumber()
    .over()
    .partitionBy(employee.name)
    .orderBy(employee.id).as("rowNumber");

query.select(employee.name, employee.id)
    .from(SQLExpressions.select(employee.name, employee.id, rowNumber)
                        .from(employee).as(employee))
    .where(Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "rowNumber").eq(1L))
    .fetch();
```

Comment: And how to do it with SQLQuery?

Comment: For SQLQuery it's best to do the same, since limit/offset handling is internally mapped to the paging functionality provided by the SQL engine.

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually in my code I need rank and not rownumber, so limit won't work. Is there a way to generate a query like the one I posted?

Comment: I am also looking for exactly same functionality and the example provided in QueryDSL page is not very helpful. :(

Comment: with JPAQuery I am getting error like  "The method from(EntityPath<?>) in the type JPAQueryBase<Tuple,JPAQuery<Tuple>> is not applicable for the arguments (SimpleExpression<String>)" for this implementation. Any work arrounds?

Answer (score 0):

As written by **@timo** Window functions (rank, row_number) are not supported by JPQL (JPA 2.1 version) and hence by JPAQuery (QueryDsl Jpa 4.1.4).

You can however rewrite your query so that is does not use rank over():

```sql
select a.* from employees a
where
(
    select count(*) from employees b
    where 
       a.department = b.department and
       a.salary <= b.salary
) <= 10
order by salary DESC
```

This is supported by JPAQuery, it probably goes like this.

```
final BooleanBuilder rankFilterBuilder = 
    new BooleanBuilder(employee.department.eq(employee2.department));
rankFilterBuilder.and(employee.salary.loe(employee2.salary));

query.from(employee)
.where(JPAExpressions.selectFrom(employee2)
            .where(rankFilterBuilder)
            .select(employee2.count())
            .loe(10))
.orderBy(employee.salary);
```