# QueryDSL 4 with RowNumber Window function

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, querydsl, row-number

I'm using query dsl with spring data.

Environment:

```
    <querydsl-apt.version>4.1.4</querydsl-apt.version>
    <querydsl-jpa.version>4.1.4</querydsl-jpa.version>
    <querydsl-sql.version>4.1.4</querydsl-sql.version>
    <spring>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring>
```

Query:

```
JPAQueryFactory query = new JPAQueryFactory(getEntityManager());

SimpleExpression<Long> rowNumber = SQLExpressions.rowNumber()
        .over()
        .orderBy(qServiceExecution.updatedAt.asc()).as("rowNumber");

List<Tuple> response = query.select(qServiceExecution.id, SQLExpressions.rowNumber()
                .over()
                .orderBy(qServiceExecution.updatedAt.asc()))
        .from(qServiceExecution)
        .fetch();
```

Exception:

```
Root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No pattern found for ROWNUMBER
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:280) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitOperation(JPQLSerializer.java:437) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:231) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:31) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]



Spring error: No pattern found for ROWNUMBER; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No pattern found for ROWNUMBER
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

Query DSL documentation: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s03.html#d0e1276

Other stack overflow question: [QueryDSL Window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797892/querydsl-window-functions)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Its long back but can you remember how did you fix this issue. Any suggestions.?!

Answer (score 1):

Window functions are not included in the JPQL specification and as such not available in any JPA implementation. You could register these functions yourself using [custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369853/2104280).

However, after this, these functions still won't be accessible in QueryDSL. You're stealing from the `SQLExpressions` here to obtain a window expression. These methods live in `SQLExpressions` for a reason: they only work with `querydsl-sql` and not with `querydsl-jpa` (again, because JPA itself does not support window functions). So after registering your custom function, you will still have to extend `JPQLTemplates` to include the template for your custom window function.

You'd do this like this:

```
public class MyTemplates extends JPQLTemplates {

    public MyTemplates() {
        add(SQLOps.ROWNUMBER, "ROW_NUMBER({0})");
    }

}
```

And then use it as follows:

```java
new JPAQuery(entityManager, new MyTemplates()).from(entity).select(rowNumber())
```

With the Spring integration in the middle however, the templates are somewhat more difficult to bind to the query I think.

---

Alternatively you could look into the [`blaze-persistence-querydsl`](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#querydsl-integration) extension, which has out of the box support for window functions (and many other features) for JPQL. For example:

```java
QCat cat = QCat.cat;

BlazeJPAQuery<Tuple> query = new BlazeJPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager, criteriaBuilderFactory).from(cat)
    .select(cat.name, JPQLNextExpressions.rowNumber(), JPQLNextExpressions.lastValue(cat.name).over().partitionBy(cat.id));

List<Tuple> fetch = query.fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late but I had the same problem, I resolved it by adding configuration files from [there](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/index.html#environments-spring)

then injected CriteriaBuilderFactory

```
 @Inject
CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf;
```

At the beginning and then write any query with window function like this

```
QProductHistory his =QProductHistory.productHistory;
SimpleExpression<Long> rown =  JPQLNextExpressions.rowNumber().over().partitionBy(his.esn).as("rown");
BlazeJPAQuery<Tuple> bl_qry = new BlazeJPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager, cbf).from(his)
            .select(his.esn, rown);

    List<Tuple> fetch = bl_qry.fetch();
```