# How to combine distinct and sort in spring data jpa specification query with joins

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**Example setup:**

*Entity*

```
@Entity
class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinTable(name = "book_authors",
            joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "book_id")],
            inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "author_id")])
    var authors: MutableSet<Author> = HashSet()

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
    lateinit var publisher: Publisher
}
```

Both Author and Publisher are simple entities with just an id and a name.

*The spring data jpa BookSpecification: (notice the distinct on query)*

```
fun hasAuthors(authorNames: Array<String>? = null): Specification<Book> {
    return Specification { root, query, builder ->
        query.distinct(true)
        val matchingAuthors = authorRepository.findAllByNameIn(authorNames)
        if (matchingAuthors.isNotEmpty()) {
            val joinSet = root.joinSet<Book, Author>("authors", JoinType.LEFT)
            builder.or(joinSet.`in`(matchingContentVersions))
        } else {
            builder.disjunction()
        }
    }
}
```

*Executing the query (pageable containing a sort on publisher.name)*

```
bookRepository.findAll(
    Specification.where(bookSpecification.hasAuthors(searchRequest)),
    pageable!!)
```

*The REST request:*

```
MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/books?authors=Jane,John&sort=publisherName,desc")
```

This results in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Order by expression "PUBLISHERO3_.NAME" must be in the result list in this case;
```

The problem is in the combination of the distinct and sort. The distinct requires the publisher name to be in the select fields to be able to sort.

How can I fix this with Specification query?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to explicitly select the `PUBLISHERO3_.NAME` column like so:

```java
query.select(builder.array(root.get("PUBLISHERO3_.NAME"), root.get("yourColumnHere")));
```

Joined columns are probably not included by default because they're out of scope with regards to the root generic type.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this. basically, if you have distinct and you want to sort, you can only use the selected columns.

what you can do is to use `row_number()` window function instead of `distinct`, and then select everything with `row_number=1`. 
you can find an (a little bit old) example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30827497/10668681